# Store PHP code in a text file and retrieve it using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, navbar

Is there any way to store PHP code in a text file (for a navbar that may change) and access this text file via file_get_contents and add it into a div in a PHP/HTML document?

Comment: Make use of `file_put_contents` to write data with a `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are trying to execute the PHP code in the external file or display it?

Comment: Display it like an iframe but in a div.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is

```
<div class="navbar">
<?php include("nav.php"); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't think it would be this easy! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in `include()` function in PHP.

See docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Using this means you essentially read in the contents of the file, and insert it directly where you are making the call. In your case it might be something like:

```
<div id="menu">
<?php include('partials/menu.php'); ?>
</div>
```

Whatever you have in the menu.php file (located in partials folder) will be inserted inside the menu div.

As a side note, since it's basically injecting whatever is in the file, you can also use any variables that you set in the `menu.php` file if need be

Answer (score 0):

Use one of these

```
www.php.net/include
www.php.net/require
www.php.net/file_get_contents and www.php.net/eval
```